# Salesforce Custom Object with lookup field to User table

Tags: salesforce

I have a custom object with a lookup field (foreign key) to the User table.  I added a "custom object" tab to my app to list these items.

What I think I want is the functionality provided by a "master detail" relation.  Sadly, this is not available when referencing the user model from a custom object.

When a given logged-in user views this tab, I want them to see any items if they have access to the User referenced in this lookup field.  I suspect that this list view is going to show all items that BELONG to the logged in user (i.e created by). It's difficult to test because of the limited user licenses available in the dev edition.

For a logged in user, what is the best way to display the correct items regardless of who created them?

Comment: Not sure I fully get the question; however, to your point about "difficult to test because of the limited user licenses available in the dev edition", if you sign up for the SFDC partner program, one of the cool features you get in the partner portal is the ability to provision test orgs, which can be any edition/license. Very useful for testing.

Comment: Thanks @jkraybill I sadly found out about the partner portal little too late.  But, it's great to know.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new lookup field to the user object, why not just use the record owner?
The record owner doesn't have to be the person that created the record, and you can then create a View for 'My Object__c' that will only show items owned by the logged in user.

If this is no help, can you please elaborate on your requirements?

Comment: Nick, I would like any user to be able to attach (via the lookup field) records of my custom type to another target user.  Anyone who has access to edit this target user, should have access to edit the custom object.  What I am trying to avoid is the case where two objects are created, each accessible by a different user.